# Trying to use CatBoostClassifier, but it doesn't see cat_cols nevertheless parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, catboost

I'm trying to apply gradient descent on my data and then evaluate model with ROC_AUC method. Previously I've tried Logistic Regression and it worked perfectly fine, but Gradient Descent model somehow gives error with the same data.

The code:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations = 100, learning_rate = 0.1, depth = 6, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train,y_train, cat_features=cat_cols)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
roc_auc
```

The error:

```
ValueError: 'Sex' is not in list
```

However, in fact there is such attribute:

`print(cat_cols)`

Output:

```
['Sex', 'IsSeniorCitizen', 'HasPartner', 'HasChild', 'HasPhoneService', 'HasMultiplePhoneNumbers', 'HasInternetService', 'HasOnlineSecurityService', 'HasOnlineBackup', 'HasDeviceProtection', 'HasTechSupportAccess', 'HasOnlineTV', 'HasMovieSubscription', 'HasContractPhone', 'IsBillingPaperless', 'PaymentMethod']
```

I've tried putting `cat_features=cat_cols` into fit() method, model itself and both, doesn't work.

What causes the model give this error?

Comment: What is the output of `print(X_train.columns)`?

Comment: @Mattravel I found out it uses one hot encoded data( 'Sex_Female', 'Sex_Male').